# Refresh data whit refreshLayout using livedata

Tags: android, android-room, android-livedata, swiperefreshlayout, android-viewmodel

i have a fragment in my app that i show two list of saparate data in it.i'm using from [android architecture components](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture) to load my data.
Once the data is fetched from the network, I store it locally using Room DB and then display it on the UI using ViewModel that observes on the LiveData object (this works fine). However, I want to be able to have a refreshLayout which When Refreshing Occurs a refresh action and perform a network request to get new data from the API if and only if there is a network connection.The issue is when Refreshing Occurs data load from locate database and network together .
my question is :**How do I manage to get data only from Network when refreshing data?**

How do I manage to get data only from Network when refreshing data?
I've seen [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54183271/refresh-data-from-a-network-using-livedata) and it didn't help me...

my codes:

**repository:**

```
    public NetworkResult<LiveData<HomeHealthModel>> getHomeHealth(String query) {

    MutableLiveData<String> _liveError = new MutableLiveData<>();
    MutableLiveData<HomeHealthModel> data = new MutableLiveData<>();


    LiveData<List<GeneralItemModel>> liveClinics = App.getDatabase().getGeneralItemDAO().getTops(GeneralItemType.Clinics, GeneralItemType.TOP);
    LiveData<List<GeneralItemModel>> liveDoctors = App.getDatabase().getGeneralItemDAO().getTops(GeneralItemType.Doctors, GeneralItemType.TOP);

    setupService(_liveError); //request data from network


    data.postValue(new HomeHealthModel(liveClinics, liveDoctors));
    _liveError.postValue(String.valueOf(NetworkResponseType.LocaleData));
    return new NetworkResult<>(_liveError, data);

}
```

my **viewModel**

```
public class HomeHealthVM extends ViewModel {

private MutableLiveData<String> queryLiveData;

private LiveData<String> networkErrors;
private LiveData<List<GeneralItemModel>> Clinics;
private LiveData<List<GeneralItemModel>> Doctors;

public HomeHealthVM(HealthRepository repository) {
    queryLiveData = new MutableLiveData<>();

    LiveData<NetworkResult<LiveData<HomeHealthModel>>> repoResult;
    repoResult = Transformations.map(queryLiveData, repository::getHomeHealth);
    LiveData<HomeHealthModel> model = Transformations.switchMap(repoResult, input -> input.data);
    Doctors = Transformations.switchMap(model, HomeHealthModel::getDoctors);
    Clinics = Transformations.switchMap(model, HomeHealthModel::getClinics);
    networkErrors = Transformations.switchMap(repoResult, input -> input.error);
}

public void search(String queryString) {
    queryLiveData.postValue(queryString);
}


public String lastQueryValue() {
    return queryLiveData.getValue();
}

public LiveData<String> getNetworkErrors() {
    return networkErrors;
}

public LiveData<List<GeneralItemModel>> getClinics() {
    return Clinics;
}

public LiveData<List<GeneralItemModel>> getDoctors() {
    return Doctors;
}
```

}

my **fragment** code:

```
    private void setupViewModel() {

    ViewModelFactory<HealthRepository> factory = new ViewModelFactory<>(new HealthRepository());
    healthVM = ViewModelProviders.of(this, factory).get(HomeHealthVM.class);

    healthVM.getNetworkErrors().observe(this, states -> {


        try {
            if (Integer.parseInt(states) != WarningDialogType.Success &&
                    Integer.parseInt(states) != WarningDialogType.Locale) {
                stopLoading();
                linerNoInternet.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                linerContent.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            stopLoading();
            linerNoInternet.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            linerContent.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    });

    healthVM.getDoctors().observe(this, doctors -> {

        if (doctors.size() > 0) {
            doctorsAdapter.submitList(doctors);
            stopLoading();
        } else {
        }
    });

    healthVM.getClinics().observe(this, clinics -> {
        if (clinics.size() > 0) {
        clinicsAdapter.submitList(clinics);

            stopLoading();
        } else {
            conesClinics.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        }
    });

    healthVM.search("");
}
```

Comment: can you share setupService() method code?

Comment: @KishanMaurya its a simpe volley request